# Java: Inherit all superclass's constructors by default

Tags: java, inheritance, optimization, constructor, code-duplication

I'm only beginner in Java.

My Superclass has several constructors:

```java
public class Superclass {
    protected Superclass () {
        //some stuff
    }

    protected Superclass (typeA a){
        //some other stuff
    }

    protected Superclass (typeB B){
        //another stuff
    }
}
```

I want to make subclasses, but all of them will only use all super constructors of Superclass and some specific for that class actions. Example for subclass:

```java
public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    protected Subclass () {
        super();
        //subclass stuff
    }

    protected Subclass (typeA a){
        super(typeA a);
        //the same subclass stuff
    }

    protected Subclass (typeB B){
        super(typeB B);
        //the same subclass stuff
    }
}
```

Does in Java exist something to inherit all superclass constructors? Because I don't want to copypaste code, but I want to do like this:

```java
@InheritsAllConstructors
public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    {
        //some stuff
    }
}
```

Or there is more suitable solution?)

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited...

Comment: No, such a mechanism doesn't exist.

Comment: If you use an IDE (such as Eclipse) it may have a function to generate the constructors for you.

Comment: Assuming none of that "some subclass stuff" is assigning final fields you can move it to a private method that is invoked by each constructor.

Answer (score 0):

NO, because subclasses are not forced to have the same constructors as their superclasses (They can have more or fewer constructors).

- **Superclass has no explicit constructors**: Subclasses are not forced to have an explicit constructor.
- **Superclass has one explicit constructor**: Subclasses are forced to have at least one constructor. The constructor in the subclass doesn't have to match the one in superclass but it should call it using `super(...)`

```java
public class Super {

    public Super(String value) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Subclasses should provide a constructor that calls `super(..)`:
Like this:

```java
private class Sub extends Super {

    public Sub(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Or even this:

```java
private class Sub extends Super {

    public Sub() {
        super("some default value");
    }
}
```

- **Superclass has more than one explicit constructor**: Subclasses are forced to provide at least one constructor that calls any of the superclass's constructors:

```java
public class Super {

    public Super(String value) {
        //...
    }

    public Super(int intValue) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Subclasses could be any of the following:

```java
private class Sub extends Super {

    public Sub() {
        super("some default value");
    }
}
```

Or:

```java
private class Sub extends Super {

    public Sub(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Or:

```java
private class Sub extends Super {

    public Sub(int intValue) {
        super(intValue);
    }
}
```

*Or any combination of those constructors.*

Comment: So to confirm: If I have a final field in `Subclass`, then I have no choice other than A) Initialising it where the field is declared in `Subclass` (outside all constructors), B) Copy-pasting the initialisation code for the final field to all constructors, or C) Finding a way to chain the various `Subclass` constructors using `this()`?